# Coldfusion can't read IRS pdf form

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

Trying to first dump the fields, so that I can later populate the form after having known the field names. Error says "Either datafile XML or data XML contained in the PDF document is invalid. "

```
<cfpdfform source="https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f941.pdf" action="read" result="result" />

<cfoutput>
    <cfdump var="#result#" />
</cfoutput>
```

[Demo](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=c2586386-69f5-45a4-a0b3-edb8516a06de/11dc48bc-7d19-41ed-8974-4d6b793b3c2d/a7b7815a-30ee-45f8-b75c-756ec5670da6.cfm)

Same code works for this file https://www.flhsmv.gov/pdf/forms/82040.pdf

Comment: I not exactly sure why this is happening. You may need to use the itext [PdfReader](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.9/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfReader.html) and [PdfStamper](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html) as the alternative. You'll need to download jar files an place them in Coldfusion lib folder. I have verified this with itext. This is probably a bug in Coldfusion.

Comment: Not all PDFs are built the same, but more importantly, the underlying libraries of ACF differ for each version.  If you can read the file correctly with the latest version of iText, it's possible that a later version of ACF will read it just fine. So it's probably in your best interest to use the iText library directly at all times so you're not limited by ACF as you upgrade it over the years.